# Undefined index during file upload

Tags: php

I already check if $_FILES is set but its  throwing this error

Notice: Undefined index: size in D:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.21-0\apache2\htdocs\imagescript\upload.php on line 16

Here is part of my code

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){

for($x = 0;$x <count($_FILES['image']['name']);$x++) { 

$file_size    = $_FILES['image']['name']['size'][$x];
```

It is the `$file_size` line that is responsible for the error

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be

```
$file_size    = $_FILES['image']['size'][$x];
```

and in loop

```
for($x = 0;$x <count($_FILES['image']['name']);$x++) { 
    $file_size    = $_FILES['image']['size'][$x];
}
```